# Extract the details from a Table using VBA gets object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

My script runs for few row and then i a getting  object variable or with block variable not set error.

I am using the below script to extract the 5,6,7 value from the NSEIndia website.

I get the value of a stock from the same Excel and update the same excel with the values from the nseindia website.

```
Sub Stock_Basic_Update_NSE()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim webpage As HTMLDocument
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
        
    For Item = 23 To 1505
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NSE Stocks Details")
       sSearch = ws.Range("A" & Item).Value
        'sSearch = Filestk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value
        Set ie = New InternetExplorer
        'ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate ("https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=" & sSearch)
        Do While ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        
        While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set webpage = ie.document
        ws.Cells(Item, 3).Value = webpage.getElementsByClassName("eq-series table-fullwidth w-100")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText
        ws.Cells(Item, 4).Value = webpage.getElementsByClassName("eq-series table-fullwidth w-100")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(6).innerText
        ws.Cells(Item, 5).Value = webpage.getElementsByClassName("eq-series table-fullwidth w-100")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(7).innerText
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
    Next Item
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the `items` in column A?

Comment: Try moving `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NSE Stocks Details")` outside of the `FOR` loop

Comment: Try using a delay `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")` just before `Set webpage` to get rid of that error. You can locate the desired elements using `.document.getElementById("equityInfo").getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText` or `.document.querySelector("#equityInfo td:nth-of-type(6)").innerText` instead of using compound classes that you are currently doing. Changing the index should fetch you the desired content.

Comment: @SIM do you mean the error is basically the value is getting printed before the page gets loaded?

Comment: @SIM, I have increased the value to 10 as it again failed after running for 20 rows... I have to run for 2000 rows. Let me tell me once it run fully.. Thannks for the support and help

Comment: @ Sim it failed again after 65 rows... is it only due to the page loading?

Comment: @JMP it is just numbers from 2 to 1505..

Comment: If your script tries to parse the value before the page is fully loaded, there is a great chance you can encounter that error and that is what I meant. Btw, do you encounter that error for any particular ticker or it just happens randomly?

Comment: @MSBalaji; yes, but what are the cells values that then get searched for?

Comment: @SIM I am getting it randomly. For example if it struck at item 5 then next time if i set the item from 5 to 1505 in the loop it again runs for few more items and gets struck randomly

Comment: @SIM now it is getting struck for a specific ticker.https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=BAJAJHIND

Comment: @JMP I have a list of Stocks and get that stocks from the excel and append it to the HTML url as like below.

Comment: @JMP https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=BAJAJHIND. The excel has the Value of BAJAJHIND and gets that and create an URL as mentioned above.

Comment: Okay, what are the fields you are interested in grabbing from there @M S Balaji?

Comment: @SIM I am interesed to get the 6,7,& 8 TD values for all a set of stocks

Comment: Valuse of this three fields `Industry`,`Symbol P/E`,`Sectoral Index`, right?

Comment: yes you are correct SIM

Comment: There is an api in place `https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-meta-info?symbol=BAJAJHIND` which when used with a header, you should see some json response containing the values you wish to grab but it doesn't seem to be working in the right way either.

Comment: @sim is there any other option you can think of?

Comment: Yep, try using selenium which works much better than IE.

Comment: I dont know SIM may need to learn that to perform...:-(

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors in your code and you hadn't wait for the full document to load. Try the following code. I have commented it. So you can see, what I have changed and why. I have tried it with the top 50 symbols.

```
Sub Stock_Basic_Update_NSE()
  'Declare always all variables
  Dim ie As Object 'I switched this from early to late binding (not required)
  Dim nodeTable As Object
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim item As Long
  Dim sSearch As String
  
  'Use this outside the loop. You only need it once
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NSE Stocks Details")
  
  For item = 23 To 1505
    sSearch = ws.Range("A" & item).Value
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = False
    'Encode symbols that are restricted for using in URLs. Like &, : or ?
    ie.navigate ("https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(sSearch))
    'It's not "While = 4" because 4 stands for "readystate = complete"
    'If you want to use "= 4" you must use "Until" instead of "While"
    'It doesn't matter what you use
    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    'Manual break to load dynamic content after the IE reports the page load was complete
    'This was your main problem
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
    
    'The needed html table has an ID. If possible use always that instead of class names
    'because an html ID is unique if the standard is kept
    'Also use a variable to save the elements
    'So you don't need to shorten the html document string in most cases because
    'it's only needed one time
    Set nodeTable = ie.document.getElementByID("equityInfo")
    ws.Cells(item, 3).Value = nodeTable.getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText
    ws.Cells(item, 4).Value = nodeTable.getElementsByTagName("td")(6).innerText
    ws.Cells(item, 5).Value = nodeTable.getElementsByTagName("td")(7).innerText
    
    'Clean up
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
  Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I marked the invisible as true and checked,  IE gave permission denied error and hence the page did not load now. I am suprised, it is working in Chrome broswer but throwing this error.

Comment: is there any VBA code to perform the same in chrome browser instead of IE?

Comment: @MSBalaji 
The only way to use another browser than IE is to use Selenium. If you got a "permission denied" you was detected as a bot. The same would be happen with Chrome. You can try to set a break for a few minutes after each 10 or another working  quantity page accesses. Or set the manual to load the dynamic content to 10 or 30 seconds. Of course the runtime of the makro will strongly increase. As long as it is faster than manual, however, that is ok. In any case it is less prone to errors.

Comment: make sense... LEt me try and confirm.

Comment: @SIM, I was able to run the script successfully. I think they NSE website blocked me and after few mins they again gives access... So run the script multiple time to get to the solution.

Comment: I was able to run the script successfully. I think they NSE website blocked me and after few mins they again gives access... So run the script multiple time to get to the solution

Comment: Thanks Both SIM & Zwenn for the timely help.

Comment: From your previous comments, it looks like your issue is solved by the suggestion of Zwenn. I suggest marking the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer to this thread. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Further, you can move the code for creating the IE object and quitting the IE outside the loop. In this way, it will use the same IE object every time instead of creating the new object every time. It will help to improve the performance of the code.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for your comment. I left the IE object in the loop on purpose. In the past I have made the experience that IE likes to bitch around if you navigate too much within an instance. But that was still under Windows 7, I have not tried it under Windows 10 yet.

Comment: I suggest you make a test with it on a Windows 10 machine. It can help to improve the performance a lot.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT If this is possible, you are certainly right and it can't hurt to check if IE's behaviour has changed in a new environment.